# Ubuntu Studio 20.04 Login doubling to a second login which won't allow a password entry, requiring reboot

Tags: suspend, login-screen

[image: Screenshot]

As stated, normally logging in fine, but after about 20 minutes the login will come up, I put in password, and instead of going to desktop, it prompts a second login, which will show a similar motif, but with "enter your password" grayed out, and no input will register, requiring reboot.

This also occurs immediately after awakening from suspend. [Images attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dc9Vy.jpg). i7 4790k/h81s2

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try change your user's password to password which contains numbers only and verify if it works. Maybe your display manager's keyboard layout is wrong there.

You could also switch to different display manager without that behavior (or bug):

```
sudo apt install lightdm && sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

or

```
sudo apt install gdm3 && sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```